# Update localized projects via console

Tags: localization, c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I use Embarcadero C++ Builder to create application with different UI languages. Currently when original project is changing I need to manually select next options from IDE main menu:

<kbd>Project</kbd> → <kbd>Languages</kbd> → <kbd>Update Localized Projects</kbd>

> [image: menu]

Is it possible to make such action, i.e. update localized projects via console (without any GUI actions)?

Another way to update localized projects is to use External Translation Manager tool (included with RAD Studio). But this way also use GUI.

Additional information can be found on Embarcadero [web page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Updating_Resource_Modules).